# Filter on multi match ES PHP

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

Starting to work on ES. I would like to be able to make a multi_match with a filter in PHP. I followed the official ES documentation but I don't understand my mistake.

Here is the code:

```
public function search_data_into_index($array)
{
    $params = [
        'index' => 'skills',
        'type' => 'people',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'multi_match' => [
                    'query' => 'react',
                    'fields' => [$array[2]],
                    'fuzziness' => 'AUTO',
                ],
                'filter' => [
                    'geo_distance' => [
                        'distance' => '300m',
                        'location' => '-25, -49'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $response = $this->client->search($params);
    print_r($response);
}
```

Here my error :

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]","line":1,"col":94}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[multi_match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `multi_match` query must be located inside `bool/must`:

```
public function search_data_into_index($array)
{
    $params = [
        'index' => 'skills',
        'type' => 'people',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
               'bool' => [
                  'must' => [  
                     'multi_match' => [
                        'query' => 'react',
                        'fields' => [$array[2]],
                        'fuzziness' => 'AUTO',
                     ]
                  ],
                  'filter' => [
                     'geo_distance' => [
                        'distance' => '300m',
                        'location' => '-25, -49'
                     ]
                  ]
               ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $response = $this->client->search($params);
    print_r($response);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still got an error with your code.
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[must] query malformed, no start_object after query name"

thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine multiple queries using [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

In JSON format your query will look like

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "react",
          "fields": [$array[2]]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "300m",
          "location": [
            "-25, -49"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```